# Manage click event on remove_nested_fields button with nested_forms gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

What I need to do is just to increase the value of a "p" tag everytime the add button is pressed or decrease the value of the same "p" tag the delete button is pressed.

Well, nested forms uses a partial to add a new row to manage a nested form inside de main form view here is my partial code:

```
<tr class="fields">
 <td>
    <%= f.text_field :nombre, class: 'form-control' %>
 </td>
 <td>
    <% 
        concat f.select :idtipodocumento, CrTipoDocumento.all.collect 
        {|p| [ p.nombre, p.id ] }, {prompt: 'Seleccione el tipo de 
        documento'}, :class=>'form-control'
    %>
 </td>
 <td>
    <%= f.text_field :documento, class: 'form-control' %>
 </td>
 <td>
    <%= f.link_to_remove raw('<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-
     hidden="true"></i>'), :class =>'btn btn-danger' %>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

In my main view y render this partial with this code:

```
         <tbody>
            <fieldset id="acreditados">
              <%= f.fields_for :cr_acreditados, :wrapper => false %>
            </fieldset>
         </tbody>
```

and I have also the add button to add new rows which works just good:

```
      <div id="addBtn">
        <% if @counter >= 1 %>
          <p><%= f.link_to_add raw('<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-
        hidden="true"></i>'), :cr_acreditados, id: 'btna', :class => 
        'btn btn-primary lta', "data-target" => "#DAC" %></p>
        <% else %>
          <p class="text-center"><h3>No dispone de mas 
          acreditaciones</h3></p>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

And Im using a javascript to update a "p tag" text every time the add button is pressed or the delete button is pressed, the javascript for the add button works just good! here is the code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.add_nested_fields').click(function(adLine){
      var cnt = document.getElementById('acd').innerHTML;
      if(cnt <= 1){
          if(cnt == 0)
          {
              alert("You cant add more rows")
              adLine.preventDefault();
              adLine.stopPropagation();
          }
          else
          {
              var res = cnt - 1;
              $('#acd').html(res);
          }
       }
       else{
             var res = cnt - 1;
             $('#acd').html(res);
       }
   });
});
```

And I want the delete button to do the inverse of that which will be to +1 to the "p tag" text, thing is, javascript code cant detect click event on the new added rows but he detects the rows loaded with data from database the moment the view loads, here is my actual js code for the delete button:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.remove_nested_fields').click(function(remLine){
    var cnt = document.getElementById('acd').innerHTML;
    cnt = parseInt(cnt,10)
    var res = cnt + 1;
    $('#acd').html(res);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

SOlved it! just have dig in a little into official documentation of the gem:
https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

He even did a method to count and limit the max of fields! here is the link:
https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/wiki/How-to:-limit-max-count-of-nested-fields